# automated conversion Mysql Table into an XML-File - Preserve hierarchy

Tags: mysql, xml, export

I want to convert the lines of my table to a an XML hierarchial structure. The mysql-table is structured like this:

```
---table structure

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carrier_template_helper` (
  `carrier_id` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tarifs_v` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_f` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `templates_f` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `page` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `customer_f_contains_str` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
```

> `replace_str` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `add_str_before` varchar(100)
>   NOT NULL,   `add_str_after` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   `call_method`
>   varchar(50) NOT NULL,   `font_size` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '8',
>   `add_xy` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0:0',   KEY `carrier_id`
>   (`carrier_id`,`tarifs_v`,`customer_f`,`templates_f`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM
>   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

```
INSERT INTO `carrier_template_helper` (`carrier_id`, `tarifs_v`, `customer_f`, `templates_f`, `page`, `customer_f_contains_str`, `replace_str`, `add_str_before`, `add_str_after`, `call_method`, `font_size`, `add_xy`) VALUES
(80, 2, 'billing_city', 'posbilling_city', 1, '', '', '', '', 'switch_to_city', 8, ''),
(80, 2, 'billing_street1', 'posbilling_street1', 1, '', '', '', '', 'switch_to_street1', 8, '');

(80, 11, 'billing_city', 'posbilling_city', 1, '', '', '', '', 'switch_to_city', 8, ''),
(80, 11, 'billing_street1', 'posbilling_street1', 1, '', '', '', '', 'switch_to_street1', 8, ''); '
```

and i need my XML to be with hierarchy of carrier_id->tarifs_v and then the rest...something like this in pseudocode

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE ...........>
<carriers>
<tarifs>
<customer_f>2</customer_f>
<tarifs_v>billing_city</tarifs_v>
<templates_f>posbilling_city</templates_f>
.
.
.
<tarifs>

<tarifs>
<customer_f>11</customer_f>
<tarifs_v>billing_city</tarifs_v>
<templates_f>posbilling_city</templates_f>
.
.
.
<tarifs>

</carriers>
```

i would really love to automate that...what tool do i use easiest and best?

Answer (score 0):

I would use mysql console  with `-X` option that returns the results as XML + an XSLT transformation.